# Replace backslash '\' with forward '/' slash in VS Code snippets with Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

##### Background:

I am adding a custom JavaScript snippet in VS Code to insert the file path of the current file. VS Code [provides variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) to get the file path but the file path contains backslashes in the path. And I want to get the path with '/' instead of '\'

eg. 'hello\world.js' -> 'hello/world.js'

VS Code also provides [variable transformations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms) using regex. I tried to replace backslashes with forward slashes but I could not make it work. I also checked similar questions but I could not any result for this specific to variable transformations in VS Code snippets. And I could not figure it out with other similar solutions as I'm new to regex.

##### What I tried:

This works fine and replaces backslashes '\' with '_'

```
"filepath": {
  "prefix": "filepath",
  "body": ["/${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/([\\\\])/_/g}"],
  "description": "Path of current file"
}
```

But if I change '_' with '/' it does not work.

```
"filepath": {
  "prefix": "filepath",
  "body": ["/${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/([\\\\])///g}"],
  "description": "Path of current file"
}
```

I tried some variations by escaping slash and using regex groups but I could not make it work.

Comment: Maybe this: `[\\\\]/\\//g` in the end. It seems that you do not need the parentheses.

Comment: It also seems that you do not need and the brackets: `\\\\/\\//g`

Comment: On testing, you do need the brackets `[\\\\]/\\//g`.  In theory, you should be able to find a way to not use the brackets but I think there may be a bug in the snippet resolution with the escapes within the transform.  You can see this because something like `\\\\t/\\//g` works - without brackets, if you know a `t` follows the \.  But otherwise the escapes are screwing up the second `/` in the transofrm.

Comment: I guess the brackets help to isolate the \\\\'s from the next / but should not strictly be necessary.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayHandzhiyski, it worked for me. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\\\\/\\//g` is your expression. That one should mean the same, because it is a choice of only one character: `[\\\\]/\\//g`.

Comment: [\\\\]/\\//g is working for me but \\\\/\\//g does not seem to work for some reason.